# Create Outlook Activex object in Javascript

Tags: html, outlook, activex

I need to show the Mail Items from Outlook in  a web page.

I used the object tag to embed Outlook View Control in a web page.

It works fine , but i need to filter the Mail Box,Using its `Filter` property.

I am not familiar with `VbScript` and got stuck here.

How can i filter the content ?

```
<object width="100%" height="500px;" classid="clsid:0006F063-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" id="ViewCtl1">
   <param name="Folder" value="Inbox"></param>
   <param name="Filter" value="????"></param>
</object>
```

It works if i set the filter property in outlook directly ,but i need a programmatic way to filter.

Please help me.

Thanks.